# Alexa AudioPlayer - PlaybackStopped event not always being received when stopping/pausing

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have a skill which plays short stories, which are MP3 files using the AudioPlayer. It works fine with selecting and playing stories, and also when asking it to stop, which triggers a PauseIntent. But in order to allow the resuming of the story from the position it was stopped, I need to get the offset in milliseconds at the time the story was stopped/paused. I am using the AudioPlayer.PlaybackStopped event for this, which includes the offset milliseconds at the time that it stopped playing.

My issue is that the AudioPlayer.PlaybackStopped event does not always come through. It seems (although not definitely proven) that this event only fires every second time I start and then stop a story. Otherwise the PauseIntent is received, but without an AudioPlayer.PlaybackStopped event.

So if someone could suggest what I may be missing to ensure I get an AudioPlayer.PlaybackStopped event each time I stop the story, I'd be grateful. This is obviously only for during the playback of a story, not the case where the story ends.

I did come across a post which indicated that one must respond to the AudioPlayer.PlaybackStarted with "shouldEndSession": True, and this did remove an error I was getting but this obviously happens before the stopping of the story so I don't think it has assisted with this problems of only sometimes getting the AudioPlayer.PlaybackEnded event.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure why are not receiving those events. Could you share sample directives you are sending to started playback and pause it?

One workaround may be to use the `offsetInMilliseconds` field found in the AudioPlayer context that should be present in the request JSON when your skill receives the AMAZON.PauseIntent. Details here: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html#audioplayer-object

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @LootlingLentils. Here is my AudioPlayer start code:

```
 return {
        "version": "1.0",
        "response": {'outputSpeech': {
            'type': 'PlainText',
            'text': statustext
            },
            "directives": [
                {
                    "type": "AudioPlayer.Play",
                    "playBehavior": "REPLACE_ALL",
                    "audioItem": {
                        "stream": {
                            "token": "12345",
                            "url": audio_url,
                            "offsetInMilliseconds": 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "shouldEndSession": True
        }
    }
```

My PauseIntent returns the following:

```
    return {
        "response": {'outputSpeech': {
            'type': 'PlainText',
            'text': 'OK'
            },
            "directives": [
                {
                    "type": "AudioPlayer.Stop",
                }
            ],
    "shouldEndSession": True
  }
}
```

It does seem that I get the PauseIntent every time, so I can get the offsetInMilliseconds from that response, but it remains unclear why the AudioPlayer.PlaybackEnded event is not firing reliably.